# What's the name of an undefined type with a bound (and the opposite)?

Tags: scala, types, terminology

Let's say I have a type hierarchy:

```
trait Root { type Self <: Root }
class A extends Root { type Self <: A }
class B extends A { type Self <: B }
```

Now, when I have a method return `a.Self`, it is reported by the compiler as `<: A`. Do such abstract types with bounds have a name? I am devising a scheme for 'rounding them up' and would like to use proper terminology differentiating these PDTs with bounds from their concrete bounds.

Comment: I think they're still called type members. And type aliases like `type Foo = Bar` are still basically ranges like `type Foo >: Bar <: Bar`, afaik

Comment: You can just call it `bounded member types`. There is no official specific names for that

Comment: Both bounded and unbouded version are "abstract type members". So this is just "abstract type member with an upper bound". See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html

Comment: When I think about them I call them self-types in my mind although usually self-types are `trait Foo { this: Bar => }` https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html